# Exchange 2003: Can I send a mail to ALL USERS with a mailbox?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2003

As an administrator or a member of an Exchange 2003 organisation, can I send a mail to every (real, human) recipient in the GAL, or do I need to create a distribution list of "All Users" first?

Comment: Maybe I need to create a "Dynamic Distribution Group" http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996561.aspx ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can create a query based distribution group.

One method I've used is to select all users within a particular OU.  It works for me as I have one OU that contains all of the staff members.

Right click an OU>select new>Query-Based Distribution Group.

Away you go.

Comment: I'm not going to get the chance to test this for a bit, but if it works (with Exchange 2003/Windows 2003 AD) it will do nicely.

Answer (score 2):

There might be a simple microsoft way of doing this.  But if not you can find out what your GAL filter is by going to ‘Exchange System Manager’ and then ‘Recipients::All Global Address Lists::Default Global Address List::General Tab’. You can then run this query with something like ldapsearch in Linux to get the mail attribute.  Something like this:

```
ldapsearch -w $PW -v -x -D "cn=Administrator,cn=Users,dc=MYDOMAIN,dc=com" "(& (mailnickname=*) (| (&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(!(homeMDB=*))(!(msExchHomeServerName=*)))(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(|(homeMDB=*)(msExchHomeServerName=*)))(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=contact))(objectCategory=group)(objectCategory=publicFolder)(objectCategory=msExchDynamicDistributionList) ))"  mail | grep mail | awk '{ print $2}'
```

You can then modify this ldap query for an attribute that will give you your human only users.

Update:

Removing: `(objectCategory=group)(objectCategory=publicFolder)(objectCategory=msExchDynamicDistributionList)` from the query might get you only your human users.

Comment: The Windows version of your query would be something like   

dsquery * "OU=Administrators,OU=Corp,DC=mydomain,DC=com" -filter "(LDAP_QUERY_GOES_HERE)" -attr mail    

Which could be piped to BLAT and used to mail all users.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution might be to mail-enable your **Domain Users** group, or some other Security group that is shared by all the users and then email that group.

Dynamic Distribution Group are not an option in Exchange 2003

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can send an email to all users in an Exchange environment. Simply do the following:

- Open New email
- Click To:
- In the Global Address List, select the top entry, hold shift, select the bottom entry.
- Click the BCC button to add those recipients to your email. BCC so that you don't have 20KB worth of names appearing in the email.

Comment: Would this also include resources (meetinng rooms), mail-enabled contacts (outside the organisation) or groups/distribution lists?

Comment: If they are mail enabled, then yes, it would. I suppose re-reading the question the specification "real, human" means this is not the ideal solution.